# R-Shiny: Editable DT Table Issue

Tags: r, shiny, dt, tibble

I am fairly new to R shiny. I am trying to create a dynamic table where user enters the column name and values. Then display this as a tibble which can be edited.

But however, even though I am able to edit it, in UI it is not reflecting on the Dataframe in which it is stored. I have plotted the data towards the end just to see if the edits are being reflected back.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tibble)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Dynamic table"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("This app allows you to create a data frame with dynamic column name and values."),
      textInput("col_name", "Enter column name:"),
      textInput("col_values", "Enter column values (separated by commas):"),
      actionButton("add_col", "Add column")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::DTOutput("df_output"),
      actionButton("plot_graph", "Plot Graph"),
      plotlyOutput("plot"),
      verbatimTextOutput("update_table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Initialize a reactiveValues object to store the data frame
  rv <- reactiveValues(df = NULL)
  
  # Update the data frame based on the user input
  observeEvent(input$add_col, {
    # Validate the user input
    validate(
      need(input$col_name != "", "Please enter a column name."),
      need(input$col_values != "", "Please enter some column values.")
    )
    # Split the column values by commas
    col_values <- unlist(strsplit(input$col_values, ","))
    # Convert the column values to numeric if possible
    col_values <- suppressWarnings(ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(col_values)), col_values, as.numeric(col_values)))
    # Create a tibble with the column name and values
    new_col <- tibble(!!input$col_name := col_values)
    # Add the new column to the existing data frame (or create a new one if NULL)
    rv$df <- if (is.null(rv$df)) new_col else cbind(rv$df, new_col)
  })
  
  # Render the data frame in the main panel
  output$df_output <- DT::renderDT({
    datatable(rv$df, editable = TRUE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$table_cell_edit, {
    # Get the information about the edited cell
    info <- input$table_cell_edit
    
    # Update the data frame according to the row, column, and value
    rv$df[info$row, info$col] <- info$value
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(rv$df, x = ~rownames(rv$df), y = ~rv$df[[2]] + rv$df[[3]] , type = 'bar') %>%
      layout(xaxis = list(title = names(rv$df)[1]),
             yaxis = list(title = names(rv$df)[2]))
  })
  
  output$update_table <- renderPrint({
    rv$df
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is the entire code bit that I tried

[image]

I am able to edit it in the UI section

[image]

But again if i sort the table or do anything else, it goes automatically back to the original values.

[image]

So how do I make the values reflect back reactive Object

Comment: Unable to test right now, but I think your `input$table_cell_edit` should be `input$df_output_cell_edit`.

Comment: You can use `server=FALSE` in `renderDT`. If you use `server=TRUE` (the default), then you have to use a proxy when you edit the table. And @Limey's comment is right.

Comment: Thank you so much for the callouts, You guys are superheroes!